# Download Android application from Play Store URL without using third party

Tags: android, apk

I want to write code to download Android application (apk) from the playstore URL without using any third-party websites or app. Is it possible to do so.

I had tried usual code for that URL, but only html is downloaded not the apk. How can I download the apk without any third party?

Any help will be utmost appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You "just" have to reverse engineer Google Play Services and Google Play Store. Decompile their code, intercept network traffic, reverse the protobuf messages, look how Google Play Store does the app download and then implement everything on your own. If you are good in reverse engineering you may be able to do so in 4-5 full time weeks.